# Library depend on a header file

Tags: cmake

Let's assume I have a project with a series of libraries. I also need to generate a header file that will be used by all of these projects. So I created a CMake file, like this:

```
project(main)

add_subdirectory(sub_1)
add_subdirectory(sub_2)
# ...
add_subdirectory(sub_n)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT CustomHeader.h
    COMMENT "Generating custom header for all the libraries"
    COMMAND ...)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${OBJECT_LIST})
```

The problem is, that I don't know how to tell CMake to run my custom command (that generates this `CustomHeader.h`) *before* it would try to build the libraries in the subfolders.

I tried `add_custom_target(TARGET MyPrebuild PRE_BUILD ...)` but I'm running on Linux, and this option only works on Windows platform according to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/add_custom_target.html).

`add_dependencies` only work between targets, and not a target and a single file.

I could, in theory, add the header to be among the source files of the individual libraries (in the sub_1, .., sub_n folders) but it feels wrong, as the header is not required to be part of those libraries.

So I just have no idea how I can make a library depend on an include file, that is not part of it.

Any tips how I can overcome this problem?

Comment: `I could, in theory, add the header to be among the source files of the individual libraries (in the sub_1, .., sub_n folders) but it feels wrong, as the header is not required to be part of those libraries.` - What do you mean by "the header is not part of the library"? The header isn't used when compile the library? Or what? In any case you may create custom target for your custom command, and make libraries dependent from this target.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for the comment. What I meant, is that the generated header is not going to be exposed in the final library. Just like you wouldn't include stdio.h in your library, while you might very well use it during the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

For make header file (re)built before a library in subdirectory is compiled, you may create *target*, which builds the file, and make the library dependent from the target:

```
# *CMakeLists.txt*
# ...
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CustomHeader.h ...)

add_custom_target(generate_custom_header DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CustomHeader.h)

# *sub/CMakeLists.txt*
# ...
add_library(libA ...)

add_dependencies(libA generate_custom_header)
```

Instead of using `add_dependencies`, you may create **header-only** library which "implements" you header and link with it:

```
# *CMakeLists.txt*
# ...
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CustomHeader.h ...)

add_custom_target(generate_custom_header DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CustomHeader.h)

add_library(libCustom INTERFACE) # Header only library
add_dependencies(libCustom generate_custom_header) # which depends on generated header

# You may even assign include directories for the header-only library
target_include_directories(libCustom INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# *sub/CMakeLists.txt*
# ...
add_library(libA ...)

target_link_libraries(libA libCustom) # Common linking with a header-only library.
```

Note, that *INTERFACE* library is a "fake" - it is never created by itself. Instead, all "features" of *INTERFACE* library are just propagated to its users.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add another library target that will both keep track of the generated headers and will help to properly configure other libraries to know where to find them (i.e. `target_include_directories`).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(testable)

set(CustomHeaderInPath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CustomHeader.example)
set(CustomHeaderPath ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/CustomHeader.h)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CustomHeaderPath}
    COMMAND cp ${CustomHeaderInPath} ${CustomHeaderPath}
    COMMENT "Generated file"
    DEPENDS ${CustomHeaderInPath})

add_library(CustomHeaderLibrary ${CustomHeaderPath})
target_include_directories(CustomHeaderLibrary PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
set_target_properties(CustomHeaderLibrary PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

add_library(LibA a.c)
target_link_libraries(LibA CustomHeaderLibrary)

add_library(LibB b.c)
target_link_libraries(LibB CustomHeaderLibrary)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC LibA LibB)
```

Note that I had to explicitly set the `LINKER_LANGUAGE` of the new target as cmake won't be able to deduce it properly if no `c` or `cpp` files are added to the library.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I tried to do this, however, it does not work for me, as my libraries in the subfolder (I called sub_1, .., sub_n; you called LibA, LibB, ...) are defined as _object libraries_ (`add_library(LibB OBJECT ${SOURCES})`) and CMake does not allow `targt_link_libraries` with object libraries.